# issue with logging in user using FOSUserBundle and FOSFacebookUser

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using FOSUserBundle and FOSUserFacebookBundle to authenticate my users. The issue is that when I visit my /login page. I have two text field with a username and password. When I input my username and password, I am getting the following error:

```
The Facebook user could not be retrieved from the session.
```

This is such a weird error because I am logging in the user via a form and not via facebook, but it's as if I am logging in the user via facebook. So I played around with my source code and here's my security.yml/firewall settings:

```
 firewalls:
            main:
                pattern: ^/.*
                form_login:
                    login_path: /login
                    check_path: /login_check     
                    provider: fos_userbundle
                fos_facebook:
                    app_url: "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/"
                    server_url: "http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php"
                    login_path: /login
                    check_path: /login_check
                    default_target_path: /
                    provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
                anonymous: true
                logout: 
                    path:   /logout
                    target: / 
                    handlers: ["fos_facebook.logout_handler"]
                #http_basic:
                #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"
            login:
                pattern:  ^/login$
                security: false
```

What I am worried about is that the /login_check, will check for facebook session to exists all the time, which I don't really want. When I change the login_path and check_path for the fos_facebook, everything works just fine. Any idea what might cause this and how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check_path should be different for form_login and fos_facebook. For example:

```
           form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check     
                provider: fos_userbundle
            fos_facebook:
                app_url: "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/"
                server_url: "http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php"
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check/facebook
                default_target_path: /
                provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
```

Comment: why is it that it's the same here https://github.com/ollietb/OhFOSFacebookUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/security.yml

Answer (score 0):

i ran into the same issue, and Carlos is right.

Following changes need to be done:

```
 form_login:
    login_path: /login
    check_path: /login_check     
    provider: fos_userbundle
 fos_facebook:
    app_url: "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/"
    server_url: "http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php"
    login_path: /login
    check_path: /login_check/facebook
    default_target_path: /
    provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
```

and in your routing.yml

```
_security_check:
  path:  /login_check
  defaults:  { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }

_security_logout:
  pattern:  /logout

_security_check_fb:
  path: /login_check/facebook
  defaults:  { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }
```

last but not least you have to edit the JS for Facebook:

```
function goLogIn(){
  window.location.href = "{{ path('_security_check_fb') }}";
}
```

So now you can login with the form or with Facebook without any problems.